# Scala XML pull parser and location

Tags: xml, scala, xmlpullparser, scala-xml

I have been asked to write a utility to search a large number of XML files for elements with a missing attribute. The department responsible cannot just make the attribute mandatory in the DTD because it will break hundreds of files. They want to edit them manually over a period of days/weeks.

I am writing a small command line tool in Scala 2.8.1. I will be using a "pull" parser so that I can keep my code functional-programming pure and run it multi-threaded.

I need the location of XML events. The API provided in Java 6 (`javax.xml.stream. XMLStreamReader`) has a method (`getLocation()`) that returns the line number of an event. I can use this to write messages that inform the user where to look for the missing attribute.

I would prefer to use the pull parser in `scala.xml.pull.XMLEventReader`, but it does not appear to offer location information.

Am I missing something? Is it somewhere else in the Scala API?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to track the source line of an XML element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446137/how-to-track-the-source-line-of-an-xml-element)

Comment: I'm amazed at how low the (original) duplicate of this question is on the list of related links. I'll try editing its title to make it closer.

Comment: Ugh. I failed to see that what I thought was a the original question was a full XML loader, while this is concerned about _pull_ reader. Sorry. I'd retract my vote to close if it was possible.

Comment: It is not a duplicate. The other question deals specifically with SAX parsers -- the API for Locator is clear. I am trying to use the Scala StAX parser. I even know how to do it in the `javax.xml.stream` package, just not the `scala.xml.pull` version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, this is not provided by the `XMLEventReader` api.

It relies on `io.Source` and could provide access to the location but does not. I don't see an easy way to go around that as the object that has access to the position is private.

You may want to make your own copy of [`XMLEventReader`](http://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/browser/scala/tags/R_2_8_1_final/src/library/scala/xml/pull/XMLEventReader.scala) that produces a custom `XMLEvent` with the position. The method to modify would be 
 `override def elemStart` which has access to the position and could generate another `EvPos(line:Int, column:Int)` after each `EvElemStart`.

You may also consider using 2.9.RC1 as certain performance related bugs were fixed.